# Migrating an ASP application between services shows ODBC Driver error: data source name not found

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2016

I'm migrating an ASP application from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2016, with an Oracle database located on another server.

I have already installed all the extensions that the application uses, configured everything related to Oracle, including downloading the same version that is on the old server, tested the connection with ODBC 32 and 64 bits on Windows, and configured the tnsnames.ora file.

I tested a connection purely in asp, and both are working, but the application itself does not connect to the database, it persists in this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I don't know if I skipped any essential steps, as I have no experience with this type of situation.

Comment: If it's using the DSN name you will need to use `odbcad32.exe` otherwise known as the ODBC Administrator to add a named connection and give it the name expected by the connection string in the ASP application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.